# No data refresh in Flask with templates

Tags: python, linux, flask, jinja2

I filled table with data from sql using flask. It works fine until I try to use templates. Even if template looks like this:

```
!doctype html> 
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello {{ result[0][0] }}</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

if I reload page, data doesn't change, but in fact it is changed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask
import get_stat
from flask import render_template    


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/") 
def index(): 
        print get_stat.showall()
        return render_template('index2.html', result = get_stat.showall(), result2 = get_stat.showsum(), online = get_stat.term_online_status()) 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8899, debug=True)
```

If I just print all data without using templates - all works fine.

`print get_stat.showall()` show no data changes also.

Comment: Can you show us example of a result, what is stored in it ?

Comment: Data doesn't matter in this case. For this moment i'm using [['Test', 50, 96, 1, 3],['Test', 30, 61, 12, 4]] with same result.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my post btw =)

Comment: i've tried string, int, dict, list, list in list. Same result. It's printed in browser, its just doesn't change after I reload page.

Comment: I answer below, maybe that will help